# Numeric variable in json style

Tags: json, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I'm stuck in my style settings as I don't know how to put a numeric variable for the "icon-rotate" attribute.

I've tried

```
"icon-rotate": "{{c}}"
 "icon-rotate": "{c}"
 "icon-rotate": "${c}"
 "icon-rotate": {c}
```

But nothing works I always got the error

> layers[10].layout.icon-rotate: number expected, string found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/. Currently properties like [`icon-image`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#layout-symbol-icon-image) & [`text-field`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-style-spec/#layout-symbol-text-field) support tokens.

But - implementing tokens across all properties is actively being discussed in this issue: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-style-spec/issues/249

Comment: Can't wait to see the big "data drinven styles" update :)